# macvtap interface in Linux Virtualization

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, qemu, kvm

Apparently using macvtap as the networking option for guest VMs provide better performance over the traditional tun/tap device with Linux bridge.

From what I understand macvtap uses the Host Linux kernel's macvlan driver, which basically creates a sort of logical ethernet interface over the physical nic by having a different mac address.

But how does using macvtap help in the throughput ? Is it because the backend handling of transmit/receive from guest VM is handled in the host kernel (as opposed to Qemu process doing it with traditional tun/tap) ?